# Net Standard 2.1 Targeting is missing from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0, net-standard-2.1

I just installed the .Net Core 3.0 SDK (both 64 and 32 bit version) and yet, the .Net Standard 2.1 Targeting Pack is not shown in Visual Studio's list. It is going up until 2.0 only. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apologizing. The problem is that I had to update visual studio.

Interestingly enough, I had Visual Studio open for several hours, and even though an update existed, it didn't prompt me to update, leaving me with the impression that it was already in the most recent version.

I had to run Visual Studio Installer manually to request for an update

Comment: VS only checks for updates from time to time, seems to be no more than daily if you don't restart it. And you can run the Visual Studio Installer directly to avoid steps when you know there is an update.